# Positioning UILabel inside UIView

Tags: ios, autolayout, nslayoutconstraint

Given the following image:

The three labels: "TODAY, AVERAGE, LAST WEEK" are positioned dynamically within my ViewController. This becomes a problem when the application is deployed to other devices (i.e. iPhone 6 Plus) where they aren't positioned properly.

I'm aware of being able to use AutoLayout however I would like to position them properly using the library that's used to generate the 3 activity bars.

The library I'm using is: [CHCircleGauge](https://github.com/chaione/CHCircleGaugeView).

I tried adding the following to this library but wasn't sure exactly what kind of constraints to use to position them where you see them in this image.

[image]

This is the code I'm using so far, which is the [same code](https://github.com/chaione/CHCircleGaugeView/blob/master/CHCircleGaugeView/CHCircleGaugeView.m) that's used to position the label "6hrs" centered horizontally and vertically.

```
NSDictionary *valueLabelDictionary = @{@"valueText" : self.valueTextLabel};
[self addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|[valueText]|" options:0 metrics:nil views:valueLabelDictionary]];
[self addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|[valueText]|" options:0 metrics:nil views:valueLabelDictionary]];
```

I simply just added the following to at least be able to play around with dynamic constraints and can successfully position the labels in the same place. But the problem is I'm not quite sure how to position them perfectly like the image above.

```
NSDictionary *titleLabelDictionary = @{@"titleText" : self.titleTextLabel};
[self addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|[titleText]|" options:0 metrics:nil views:titleLabelDictionary]];
[self addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|[titleText]|" options:0 metrics:nil views:titleLabelDictionary]];
```

[image]

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I'm still trying to get my head around how AutoLayout and constraints work.

**UPDATE:**

In order to display the three rings I use the following:

```
var barView1 = CHCircleGaugeView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 245, 245))
barView1.center = CGPointMake(self.gaugeView.frame.size.width / 2, self.gaugeView.frame.size.height / 2)
barView1.gaugeWidth = 16
barView1.gaugeTintColor = UIColor(red: 255/255, green: 202/255, blue: 76/255, alpha: 1)
barView1.trackWidth = barView1.gaugeWidth
barView1.trackTintColor = UIColor(red: 255/255, green: 202/255, blue: 76/255, alpha: 0.1)
self.gaugeView.addSubview(barView1)
barView1.setValue(0.10, animated: true)
```

Then I simply add two more that are of smaller size (centered in `gaugeView`) to fit inside the larger ring.

**UPDATE 2:**

I ended up using the following with some `constant` padding:

```
[self addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.titleTextLabel
                                                 attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop
                                                 relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                    toItem:self
                                                 attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop
                                                multiplier:1.0
                                                  constant:-9.0]];

[self addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.titleTextLabel
                                                 attribute:NSLayoutAttributeRight
                                                 relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                    toItem:self
                                                 attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX
                                                multiplier:1.0
                                                  constant:-14.0]];
```

Comment: Do you control the thickness of each ring?

Comment: @AaronBrager: Yes, that's done by setting the `gaugeWidth` and `trackWidth` properties of the object to `16`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you're new to auto layout, so I'll try to point you in the right direction without giving it all away.

**Vertical Constraints**

Constrain each label's Y to the top of the ring instead of the center. Set each label's top constraint's `constant` slightly differently so they appear stacked on top of each other. The `constant` should be `trackWidth * (labelIndexNumber)`. So they'll end up being `0`, `16`, and `32`.

This way if you ever change `trackWidth` your labels will adjust automatically. You may need to play with my numbers slightly to get the padding right.

**Horizontal Constraints**

Constrain the right side of each label to the circle view's center. I don't think you can use VFL for this; you'll have to use the verbose `[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:…` syntax.

**Label Settings**

Your label's text should be right-aligned. You might need to increase the horizontal compression resistance, depending on your other views, but avoid that if you can.

Comment: All of what you've said makes sense, I'll take a crack at seeing if I can give it a go myself. I really appreciate your detailed answer.

Comment: @gotnull I saw you deleted your follow-up. Did you get it working?

Comment: I've updated my question with the code I've used. It seems to be working fine, however I just used some padding for the `constant` values as I couldn't really figure out what you meant with the multiplication.